# Need help with an IR demodulation circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, infrared, reverse-engineering, single-supply-op-amp

I'm trying to reverse engineer a PCB and made a schematic.

The bad thing is I only have PCB images from both sides, not the actual PCB. This PCB is used to detect a very small black object spinning at the speed of 23000 RPM.

I need to know the following things about the schematic:

1. Can any one help me learn the working of this circuit? I know the bottom one is an inverting op-amp, but I don't know about the top one.
2. The op-amp IC is an [LM324A](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm324.pdf) and they are running it on 1.65 V. Is it possible to run it at 1.65 V? The suggested voltage for the IC is more than 3 V.

[image]

Here is my actual PCB on which I'm working:

[image]

Comment: Yes i need help. Actually i don't know much about this circuit.  I know bottom one is inverting Operational amplifier but I don't know about the upper one I think it's amplifier with peak detector circuit. Actually I'm looking someone to explain the upper one.

Comment: mastermind - I was offering to help you *with the edit to fix the incorrect op-amp part number you showed originally* (no need to reply to that - I've done it now). My experience is that trying to reverse-engineer PCB images (without the physical PCB) is rarely an efficient use of time and is often unsuccessful, unless the PCB is very simple.  (I especially can't help in this case, since from a few quick checks, I disagree with the partial schematic you have drawn already e.g. C16/R39 which you show, and I would have to start again from the beginning.) However I wish you sincere good luck!

Comment: Operation of LM324 on 1.65V SHOULD be impossible. Common mode voltage is 2V max and maybe 1.5V typical. U4C pin 10 is in the illegal range at 1.65V and in all cases headroom is about zero, if that. At 3V operation is possible with care. Where is the 1.65V from?

Comment: Are you SURE about the 1.65V?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - Hi, Regarding: "*Operation of LM324 on 1.65V SHOULD be impossible*". I was just looking at that for the same reason 5 minutes ago, and you're right! I found that the claimed 1.65 V is another part of the PCB which has been reverse-engineered wrongly (just like I don't believe C16 and R39 share a common node). This raises more doubts about how much (and which parts) of the provided schematic can be trusted, *if any at all*.

Comment: It would probably be easier to find a circuit that did the same job. U4C maintains a fixed DC level and produces pulses at output. Negative edges are coupled to comparator U4d to produce positive output pulses. There will be many cc=ts available that do this.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon  Yes, U4C produces pulses at output, I have tested it on hardware. You have used the term "fixed DC level" can you explain it?     Also can you please explain the purpose of this common emitter transistor used here?

Comment: 1.65V is exactly half of 3.3V. It might be referenced to the mid-point of a 3.3v supply that is used for the logic. The power pins of the LM324 are not shown.

Answer (score 2):

The 1.65V is a midpoint reference for a the op-amp, which is using a single-ended supply (perfectly fine with the LM324.) The details of that supply would be interesting; my guess is that they use another LM324 as a ‘rail splitter’ to generate it.

The LM324 power connections aren’t shown, but they’re probably GND and 3.3V.

Answer (score 1):

## 1

I would go through the most common configurations.

- Voltage follower
- In/non-inverting
- In/non-summing
- Differential
- Integrator
- Differentiator

It could be a peak detector too.

---

## 2

From the datasheet:

[image]

Comment: That is not the correct datasheet and not the correct section of the datasheet you do link to. The correct section is the "Recommended Operating Conditions". The minimum operating voltage is 3V. And it is not going to be very good at that because of the common-mode limitations.

Comment: Tip: the standard on SE sites is to use quotation markdown for quotes rather than bold as you have done. `>` or `>1. ` for numbered list items.

Comment: I don't want to quote sources and quote the OP. I tried that with the last one, and it was just confusing.

Comment: Quoting sources is requested here whenever possible. It can be very unobtrusive. eg you can see images of me [here](http://bit.ly/oldgreyguy) .